# How to minimise differences between browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, web, html

So we all know that different elements of a webpage may appear differently between different browsers. I am very new to this, but I was just wondering; *what steps can be taken to **minimise** the differences between different browsers*? By elements, I mean anything that affects the user experience, such as the *appearance*, *interaction*, etc. Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many website developers and frameworks use a reset or normalize css in order to standardize on all element styling rules.
Such as removing the form element padding/margin that is in IE but not FireFox.

I recommend researching front-end web frameworks that will work for you, such as twitter bootstrap, which is very commonly used.
http://getbootstrap.com/

The front-end web framework will standardize all layouts/styles/interactions and provide the ability to follow best practices and compatibility with most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). From its page:

> Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The editor here was fooling around with me. Updated.

Comment: Is this a common solution? As in, are many people aware of it?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty popular. I mean, like really popular. See also on Github: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/ Pretty popular.